# How to pull a Docker Image in Jenkins

Tags: docker, visual-studio, jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I have a Docker Image called "build-ccsmp-ol8-x86", and I want to pull this image into my Jenkins Job.
I tried this-

```
node ('dev2-165') {
  docker.image('node:build-ccsmp-ol8-x86').inside {
    sh 'node --version'
  }
}
```

But I am getting Error saying-

```
+ docker inspect -f . build-ccsmp-ol8-x86
 
Error: No such object: build-ccsmp-ol8-x86
```

Is there any way to do this correctly? Any suggestions are highly appreciated.

Comment: Is that a custom image from a private registry? Is your pipeline targeting the private registry?

Comment: Hi I was able to solve the issue myself but Thank you sooo much for taking the time to answer my question I highly appreciate it.